# A Recursive Method in Java that returns an arrayList of integers (just one of them) which sum up to a number or null if there is none

Tags: java, recursion, arraylist

I am trying to use recursion to write a method subsetWithSum(ArrayList numbers, int sum), that that takes an arrayList of integers and an integer sum and returns an ArrayList which contains numbers from the given *numbers*(the provided ArrayList) that sum up to sum. It is not necessary to return more than one combination, and if there is no such subset, it should return null. But my code only returns null for each one.``

Here is my code for the method:

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> subsetWithSum(ArrayList<Integer> numbers, int sum){
    ArrayList<Integer> sumList=new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int sumForNumbers=0;
    for (int i=0; i<=numbers.size()-1; i++)
        sumForNumbers+=numbers.get(i);
    if (sumForNumbers==sum)
        return numbers;
    else if(sumForNumbers>sum || numbers.size()==0)
        return null;
    else {
        for (int i=0; i<numbers.size();i++){
        int n=numbers.get(i);
        for (int currentIndex=i+1; currentIndex<numbers.size(); currentIndex++)
            sumList.add(numbers.get(currentIndex));
        for (int currentIndex=0; currentIndex<=numbers.size()-1;currentIndex++){
            if ((sumForNumbers+numbers.get(currentIndex))<=sum){
                sumList.add(numbers.get(currentIndex));
                sumForNumbers+=numbers.get(currentIndex);
            }
        }
    }
        return subsetWithSum(sumList, sum);
    }
}
```

and here is my call to the method in the main:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Integer> test = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    test.add(3); test.add(11); test.add(1); test.add(5);
    System.out.println("Available numbers: " +test);
    for(int sum=16; sum<=19; sum++){
        ArrayList<Integer> answer = subsetWithSum(test, sum);
        System.out.println(sum+" can be made with: "+answer);
```

here is my present output:

```
Available numbers: [3, 11, 1, 5]`
16 can be made with: null
17 can be made with: null
18 can be made with: null
19 can be made with: null
```

my expected output is:

```
Available numbers: [3, 11, 1, 5]
16 can be made with: [11, 5]
17 can be made with: [11, 1, 5]
18 can be made with: null
19 can be made with: [3, 11, 5]
```

I find recursion really difficult to understand and any help would be great

Comment: Something like [How to return an ArrayList with an recursive function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27886116/how-to-return-an-arraylist-with-an-recursive-function) perhaps to help understanding. Remember that with recursion, all parent local variables are pushed on a stack when you recursively call the same method.  When a method returns the stacked local variables (we called it a thunk) is popped. This way you never loose your place.  Try it with a sheet of paper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, if you are using Java 8, summing a `List<Integer> list` is as simple as `list.stream().mapToInt(n -> n).sum()`.

Secondly, recursion always takes a similar form:

```
func(context)
    if context in simple form
        return simple result
    else
        break context down into smaller pieces
        call func on smaller pieces
```

In your case, it would look like

```
func(total, list)
    if sum(list) == total
        return list
    else if list is not empty
        get all solutions from func(total - first item, list without first item)
        and func(total, list without first item)
```

There are a few tricky things to consider here:

- How to handle returning both the list and whether it is a valid result
- how to remove items and then add them back after the recursive call

Here's a sample solution with a test case.

```
public class ListSum {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        subsetsThatSumTo(18, Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)).forEach(System.out::println);
    }

    public static List<List<Integer>> subsetsThatSumTo(int total, List<Integer> list) {
        List<List<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<>();
        if (list.stream().mapToInt(n -> n).sum() == total) {
            result.add(new ArrayList<>(list));
        } else if (!list.isEmpty()) {
            subsetsThatSumTo(total - list.get(0), list.subList(1, list.size())).forEach(result::add);
            result.forEach(l -> l.add(0, list.get(0)));
            subsetsThatSumTo(total, list.subList(1, list.size())).forEach(result::add);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

If you just want to return the first result:

```
public class ListSum {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(subsetThatSumTo(18, Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)));
    }

    public static List<Integer> subsetThatSumTo(int total, List<Integer> list) {
        if (list.stream().mapToInt(n -> n).sum() == total)
            return new ArrayList<>(list);
        if (list.isEmpty())
            return null;
        List<Integer> result = subsetThatSumTo(total - list.get(0), list.subList(1, list.size()));
        if (result != null) {
            result.add(0, list.get(0));
            return result;
        } else {
            return subsetThatSumTo(total, list.subList(1, list.size()));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you mean `sum(list) > total`? --- Also, `call func` should be with "(list of items *after* this item)", otherwise you'll end up wasting time trying to use the earlier values, and you already know they won't work.

Comment: I understood this concept, but my main problem arises in the recursive case which I am unable to work out, if you could help with that, that would be great.

Comment: I've posted some sample code. Hopefully that will make it clearer.

Comment: I have an understanding of what you are doing here, but I'm still confused as to how to implement it in my own method because, this method returns a list of a list of integers, but I am trying to get mine to not need a list of a list, but only return one subset that has this sum, if you could throw some light on how I could do that, that would be great

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you should be aware of is that this problem is NP-Complete. This implies its running time is not polynomial. The best known algorithm is exponential. If you find a polynomial algorithm to solve it, and you can prove it correct, you win 1M$ ;)

Reference:
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem

Now, in this case, you can apply the backtracking pattern:

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking

Just translate the pseudocode into Java and implement the functions. You'll learn a lot about recursion if you study this pattern and practise using it for different problems.